# Can we find equivalent norms for ordinary numbers $m$ and $M$ s.t. $0<m<M$?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm and $0<m<M$. Can we say that we can find another norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ s.t. $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ are equivalent with respect to numbers $m$ and $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a trivial sort of way, let $\rho \in (m,M)$, then let $\|x\|_* = \rho \|x\|$.

Then $m\|x\| \le \rho \|x\| = \|x\|_* \le M \|x\|$.